# Facebook/Gmail/Whatsapp/Twitter deep linking in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, deep-linking

I could not find a specific solution. please give me step by step solution so that i can integrate the deep linking of Facebook, Gmail, Twitter and Whatsapp. i have applied the library of google play services and facebook sdk and also unable deep linking in my account but i did not find the code for make my app link. please give me solution. Thank you

Comment: This is my manifest code.<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="appName"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

Comment: what are the functionalities you are expecting from deep linking?

Comment: my app contain share functionality in which i want to open my app whenever any user click on my share thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can deeplink if the application provides their SDK. fortunately facebook, gmail, and twitter provides SDK, but whats app not providing any sdk. so you can deep link all other applicaiton you listed out with your app, but not WhhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer (only for FB)
According to your requirement you need to do extra works to ensure deep linking.

For FB:

1. Create a fb app with share permission ( you need to get approval so that user can share from your app using fb sdk )
2. While sharing you must share your website which contains meta data for Android/iOS device (check android/iOS developer page for that meta data)
3. Now if user clicks on the share content using mobile they will be taken directly to the app. If they click from the desktop device, you can redirect them to html version or to google play site or whatever page you like.

I suspect Google and Twitter has similar mechanism.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you give me any demo so that i can understand what should be content of metadata.